# Struggling with methodizing my main program (a method that has a LinkedList as input and output specifically). Where am i going wrong with this?

Tags: java, methods, io, linked-list

first off thank you for the pointer that something.endsWith doesn't do what i was expecting it to do yesterday. Now the reason i would like to borrow your brains today is the following; i have written my program and it does exactly what i need but it's all in a chunky 'main' so i wanted to shift some parts of the code to methods to make it more readable/mantainable and i am struggling with a method that works with a LinkedList.

The code as part of the main program was as follows:

```
/* Variable definition */
List mzList = new LinkedList();
mzList = new ArrayList();

/* Reading the input file */
try {
   FileInputStream a_stream = new FileInputStream("./precursors");
   DataInputStream a_in = new DataInputStream(a_stream);
   BufferedReader a_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(a_in));
   String a_line;
   while ((a_line = a_reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if (a_line.equals("---")) {
         /* Do Nothing... */
      } else {
         mzList.add(a_line);
      }
   } /* ends the loop that reads input file */
   a_in.close(); */
}
```

I have been trying to write this into a method as follows:

```
public static LinkedList filereader (String filename, LinkedList someList) {
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if (line.equals("---")) {
         /* Do Nothing... */
      } else {
         someList.add(line);
      }
   }
   in.close();
   return(someList);
}
```

I would then attempt to call this in the main program as follows:

```
mzList = class.filreader("precursor",mzList);
```

which gives me a bunch of problems, obviously i am doing something stupid and i beg forgiveness for my harassing you all with this problem but i am quite new to Java and searching through the other 'questions' didn't really help me solve my problem.

Kind Regards,
Bas Jansen

PS: Edited some blatant typo's and formatting errors

Comment: Add your stack trace, it makes giving an answer much easier.

Comment: Reading quickly how that works as i have never did that before, gimme a few.

Comment: Ah, a stack trace is simply the output that Java gives when there is an error (ie. NullPointerException at org.etc...) ;-)

Comment: I feel stupid now... i fixed the problem by doing what the other 2 posters suggested however so i don't really have access to the stack flow anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I never tried to call method of my class with keyword `class`. If we say that your class is named `Foo`, in your Main method you should write:

```
mzList = Foo.filreader("precursor",mzList);
```

In your first Main example, this doesn't make sense:

```
List mzList = new LinkedList();
mzList = new ArrayList();
```

It should be either LinkedList() or ArrayList(), like so:

`List mzList = new LinkedList();` or `List mzList = new ArrayList();`

Next, you are passing file name "precursor", but in the first example you are using "./precursors" (but I think you are aware of that).

Lastly you are assigning result of your method to variable `mzList`, and pass the same list instance as parameter. If you pass list as parameter, you don't have to return it back because it the very same list as created earlier in your code (read about references). You could use something like this:

```
public static void filereader (String filename, LinkedList someList) {
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if (line.equals("---")) {
         /* Do Nothing... */
      } else {
         someList.add(line);
      }
   }
   in.close();
   return(someList);
}
```

and then simply (notice there is no assignment):

```
Foo.filreader("precursor",mzList);
```

As far I see, you are not making use of this input list in terms of reading data from it. Thus, you can initialize your list inside the method and return it, like so:

```
public static LinkedList filereader (String filename) {
   LinkedList someList = new LinkedList(); // notice list initialization
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
   DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if (line.equals("---")) {
         /* Do Nothing... */
      } else {
         someList.add(line);
      }
   }
   in.close();
   return(someList);
}
```

and then simply call your method and assign your results:

```
mzList = Foo.filreader("precursor");
```

Comment: That makes sense indeed, i was still defining the list outside of the method which is rather unnecessary. I will try this now, and yes the class wasn't called class but i just used class.filereader to show abstractly how i called it, sorry for not being clear there.

Comment: It confused me since `class` is a keyword in Java ;)

Comment: Yeah i realized that as soon i read your question :P Now... on to the curly braces bug fixing o.O

Answer (score 1):

Argument type of function is `Linked List` where as you have initialized your `mz_list` to `ArrayList`.

remove this `mzList = new ArrayList();` from your variable definition.

Moreover, since `mz_list` is defined at class level, and you are passing `mz_list` as an argument and then returning `mz_list`, there is no need of LinkedList as an argument for function.

You can simply have your function definition like

```
public static LinkedList filereader (String filename) {
// use mz list here
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't i lose the capability of dynamic resizing of mzList if i remove that line from my variable definition? I have to admit that i have lost you on the second part of your answer :( (What exactly is the difference between the function definitions?).

Comment: @BasJansen nops, u will not remove dynamic behaviour, u can still add as many elements as you want. Yes, there was error in the answer, I have edited that.

Comment: Sweet, then i can remove several lines of redundant code :) The second part was also pointed out to me by jjczopek so kudos to you both.